# How to skip data-sets with incorrect number of columns in loop?

Tags: r, loops, controls

I am looping though a list of file address paths in `path`. 
something like `"ProcessedFiles/2014_12/XCP2P018PORTFO_20141224.CSV"`

The aim is to stick together lots of CSV files into one big data frame. I have the flowing:

```
OUTPUT <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:nrow(paths)){


  PORT_TMP <- read.table(as.character(paths[i,]), sep = ";", header = TRUE, row.names = NULL)


  OUTPUT <- rbind(OUTPUT, PORT_TMP)

  cat(i)

}
```

The problem occurs when some data-frame doesn't have the same number of columns which stops the loop and causes an error. There's 1 or 2 files in my 1000+ long list which have an incorrect number of columns. My loop thus fails when i `rbind()`. I'd like to skip those datasets. The correct number is 47 so i am trying something like:

```
    OUTPUT <- data.frame()


    for (i in 1:nrow(paths)){


      PORT_TMP <- read.table(as.character(paths[i,]), sep = ";", header = TRUE, row.names = NULL)

      if ncol(PORT_TMP) == 47 {

      OUTPUT <- rbind(OUTPUT, PORT_TMP)
      }

      cat(i)

    }
```

I am getting some errors and not a pro at the if statements. if anyone could help this potentially simple problem i'd much appreciate.

Comment: it's running now, we'll see if it skips! nearly had it. thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in the comments:

```
if (ncol(PORT_TMP) == 47)
```